# Were Darth Vader duplicates ever used by the Empire or Rebels?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Due to nature of Darth Vader's presence, there was no way for anyone to verify Vader's identity (talking about *Force Presence*, there was a thing called *Force Stealth*).

Did Empire ever use Darth Vader duplicates to do its tasks? Mere Vader's presence could have made a job done thanks to his terror personality. In case Vader was not available, it could be useful.

Or, did Rebels ever try that? Well, using Vader duplicates, big things could be accomplished like gathering intel etc.

Legends is welcome...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Disney Canon

**Unknown.** Certainly none are seen on screen in any of the theatrical films, novelisations, TV Series or canon comics. It's theoretically possible (cloning and holographic technology are definitely a 'thing' and his outfit should be pretty easy to replicate) but there's no indication that the rebellion or the Empire ever tried it.

### EU Canon

Yes, kinda. There was a Vader clone seen in "[Galaxy of Fear : Clones](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Clones-Star-Wars-Galaxy-Fear/dp/0553486411)", a young-reader novel. I won't spoil the plot but as you can see from the book cover, the real Vader doesn't take kindly to finding out.

[image]

Comment: For the record, don't read any of the "Galaxy of Fear" novels. They're drivel.

Comment: Well, if you don't want me reading the novel, you better put the plot up in a spoiler tag.

Comment: @omegacron - I was being ironic. The entire plot is basically on the cover.

Comment: Well... now you've spoiled the whole thing. Way to go.